# 'DemoProject::Logger' : 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++

I've read a lot of questions regarding this matter, but none of them seem to solve my issue. Code below:

`Logger.cpp`

```
#include "Includes.h"

namespace DemoProject {
    class Logger {
    public:
        static void Logger::printm(CEGUI::String Message) {
            std::cout << currentDateTime() << " >> " << Message << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        static const std::string currentDateTime() {
            time_t     now = time(0);
            struct tm  tstruct;
            char       buf[80];
            tstruct = *localtime(&now);
            strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d-%m-%Y %X", &tstruct);

            return buf;
        }
    };
}
```

`logger.h`

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H
#pragma once

#include "Includes.h"

namespace DemoProject {
    class Logger {
    public:
        static void Logger::printm(CEGUI::String Message);
    };
}

#endif
```

`Includes.h`

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H
#define INCLUDES_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <CEGUI/CEGUI.h>
#include <CEGUI/RendererModules/OpenGL/GLRenderer.h>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

#include "Logger.h"

#endif
```

Sorry for bad formating of the post, but that's the best I could do. I am mostly a C# developer, but I am trying to learn C++ through doing different exercises I create on my own. From a C# developers view, this code is okay, but I don't know, I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you're doing weird. But the most important is you don't need to declare the class again in the .cpp file. You just implement the functions:

```
namespace DemoProject {

    void Logger::printm(CEGUI::String Message) {
        std::cout << currentDateTime() << " >> " << Message << std::endl;
    }

    static const std::string currentDateTime() {
        ...
    }

}
```

You also didn't declare currentDateTime in the header, so that won't compile right. You also don't need to scope the class in the declaration since you're already in the class, so your header should look like:

```
namespace DemoProject {
    class Logger {
    public:
        static void printm(CEGUI::String Message);
        static const std::string currentDateTime();
    };
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, but I got another one which I can't even understand. Thanks, though, for helping me with this matter @pinkboi